# how to get orderlist detail through flipkart seller api in php

Tags: php

```
$app_id='*********************************';
$app_secret='*******************************';
$scope = 'Seller_Api'; 

$base_url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/?"

$url_params =
    array(  

          'access_token' =>"********************",
          //'orderItemIds'=>'*************',
          'client_id' => $app_id,
          'client_secret' => $app_secret,

        //'reresh_token' =>"************************************"

);


         // $url_params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
          $url_parts = array();
            foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
            $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
            //sort($url_parts);



            // var_dump($url_parts);die;
            $url_string = implode("&",$url_parts);
             // var_dump($url_string);die;
            $url = $base_url.$url_string;

            //print_r($url);die;

            $response=file_get_contents($url);

             print_r($response);die;

?>
```

My problem is I need get order list detail through flipkart seller api, but I can't get all order details but I get only orderitemid through get data. So I want to fetch all order detail through flipkart seller api generate error....

> Mandatory parameter `orderItemIds` missing...

I need an orderlist detail so what I can do?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to get that token. i am getting empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this document [here](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIRef.html#post-orders-search)

Make a post request to this url

```
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/search
```

Use these optional parameter to search the orders. You can use orderDate parameter to search the orders happened in a specific day

```
orderDate:
    fromDate
    toDate

String  Optional    Filter based on orders placed within the selected date range, where the date strings are in ISO format

dispatchAfterDate:
    fromDate
    toDate

String  Optional    Filter based on orders to be processed within the selected date range, where the date strings are in ISO format

dispatchByDate:
    fromDate
    toDate

String  Optional    Filter based on orders to be dispatched within the selected date range, where the date strings are in ISO format

modifiedDate:
    fromDate
    toDate

String  Optional    Filter for orders that were modified within the selected date range, where the date strings are in ISO format
```

states  List    Optional    Filter orders based on a comma separated list of valid order states. Filtering based on processing states is not supported now. Possible values: APPROVED,`PACKED`, READY_TO_DISPATCH, and CANCELLED
sku     List    Optional    Filter orders based on a comma separated list of seller SKUs

Use this sample code

```
$url  = "https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/search";
$curl = curl_init(); 
$searchData = '{
          "filter": {
            "orderDate": {
              "fromDate": "2015-11-05T08:15:30Z", //refer ISO formate date
              "toDate": "2015-12-05T08:15:30Z"
            }
          }
        }';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $searchData);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//try to make it as true. making ssl verifyer as false will lead to secruty issues 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization:Bearer '.$tokan['access_token'],
''
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response
```

Comment: Thank for this answer. But please can you help me to get shipment detail. I m calling this api URL - https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/shipments?orderItemsIds={orderitemid}. but everytime getting an error [code] => INVALID_ITEM_IDS.